# Issues getting JSON object array values when they are an integer

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to make a function that iterates through all the objects in an array returned to me by the server. Here's the structure that is listed when I `console.log` my response.

[image: structure]

Now I made a javascript function that looks like this—

```
var createPosts = ((data) => {
var postsArrayLength = data.response.total_posts;

    for ( i = 0; i < postsArrayLength; i++ ) {
        //for each post create a div
        var postDiv = document.createElement('div');
        postDiv.className = 'post ' + data.response.posts.postsArrayLength[i].type;
    }
});
```

and I'm receiving this error—

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

It seems to only be giving me this error when I try to get an object that has an integer as its name.

Is there a way to deal with this? Or am I going about this completely wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Change `data.response.posts.postsArrayLength[i].type` to `data.response.posts[i].type`

Comment: Thank you, this worked! Didn't realise I could access the array directly.

Answer (score 3):

Rewrite your function to something like this:

```
var createPosts = data => {
    for ( i = 0; i < data.response.posts.length; i++ ) {
        //for each post create a div
        var postDiv = document.createElement('div');
        postDiv.className = 'post ' + data.response.posts[i].type;
    }
};
```

Comment: Sure, still a valuable answer. +1. ;)